# How to use External Procedures in Triggers on Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to fire a trigger whenever an insert command is fired..

The trigger will access a pl/sql file which can change anytime..

So the query is, if we design the trigger, how can we make sure this dynamic thing happens.. As during the stored procedure, it is not working..

I think - it should work for

```
1) External Procedures 
2) Execute Statement
```

Please correct me, if I am wrong.. I was working on External Procedures but i am not able to find the way to execute the external procedure from here on..

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Plstojavafac_func (N NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
  2  LANGUAGE JAVA
  3  NAME 'Factorial.J_calcFactorial(int) return int';
  4  /
```

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER student_after_insert
  2  AFTER INSERT
  3  ON student
  4  FOR EACH ROW
```

How to call the procedure from heree... And does my interpretations are right,, plz suggest..

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an utter mishmash of half-baked ideas.  External procedures do not run PL/SQL (they are PL/SQL wrappers to OS libraries probably written in C).  Likewise Java Stored Procedures are something different again. It would be a good idea if you were to clearly explain your **requirement**: "trigger will access a pl/sql file which can change anytime".  What does this file do?  In what way is it dynamic?  The reason why it has to be dynamic would be interesting but might not be relevant to the solution.

Comment: How about a clear statement. The user/application inserts a row into this table. When this happens I want it to "...." (eg send an email, call a web service, write to a file...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Triggers Query..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862664/oracle-triggers-query)

Answer (score 0):

either use procedure for inserting where you will handle your data and then quit procedure (cancel insert) or make successful insert, or do your data handling in trigger not in procedure